# Closing application's windows (OSX)

Tags: macos, user-interface, window

How can I close all of my open windows in Mac?

In windows we're using `EnumWindows()` and then `SendMessage(hwnd, WM_NCDESTROY, 0, 0)`
Is that the approach we should adopt also in OSX or that there's a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you’re using Carbon or Cocoa for your interface.

If you’re using Cocoa and Objective-C, it’s as easy as:

```
- (void)closeAllWindows {
    [[NSApp windows] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(performClose:)
                                     withObject:nil];
}
```

What this basically does is ask the global `NSApplication` object for its array of [-windows](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/windows).

Alternatively, you may want to specify [-close](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/close) in place of [-performClose:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/performClose%3a), depending on the type of windows you have in your app. See the documentation to determine which might be the more appropriate method to use.

If you’re using Carbon and the Carbon Event Manager, I’ll have to leave that to others, as I have no idea. ;-)